# Jackson ObjectMapper setVisibility Warnings, Pros and Cons?

Tags: java, jackson, fasterxml

I'd like to keep implemenetations functionalities non-intrusive. Having said that, `getters` for private fields just to allow objectMapper to ser/deserialize objects bothered me quite a long time. So I started using `ObjectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);`

Can anyone with objectMapping experience give me warnings on configuring `ObjectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);`?